Snakemake SLURM Executor Causes "srun: fatal" Unless mem_mb Is Set to None
I am new to Snakemake and am trying to run it on a high-performance computing cluster. I have a simple first rule at the top of my Snakefile called target that I use to debug Snakemake:
rule target:
    input:
        "figures/test.txt"
    shell:
        "touch figures/test.txt"

This rule is called when I call Snakemake with no output arguments. When I am on the cluster, I am trying to use the Snakemake SLURM executor plugin to run this rule in a job. I am doing this by entering the directory with the Snakefile and running the following command directly on the command line:
snakemake --executor slurm --cores 1 -j unlimited --default-resources slurm_account=<my account> slurm_partition=<my partition> runtime=5
Doing so results in the following error, captured by Snakemake logs:
srun: fatal: SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU, SLURM_MEM_PER_GPU, and SLURM_MEM_PER_NODE are mutually exclusive
I understand that these values are mutually exclusive, and I know that Snakemake sets mem/mem_mb by default, but I have not set per-CPU, per-GPU, or per-node memory anywhere. When I use the flag --default-resources mem_mb=None, the job successfully runs, regardless of any other flags I have.
I have tried setting values to, or setting to None, all of the following options: mem_mb_per_cpu, mem_mb_per_gpu, mem_per_cpu, mem_per_gpu, nodes, disk_mb, mem_mb. The job runs if I have mem_mb=None, no matter what other flags I specify, even if all other memory allocations are set to None as well. The job does not run in any other case.
Notes: I am not calling any batch scripts. I have set no profile, workflow-profile, or configfile defaults for SLURM execution. My package versions are below.
Python Version: 3.12.3
snakemake Version: 8.10.8
snakemake-executor-plugin-slurm Version: 0.4.5
snakemake-executor-plugin-slurm-jobstep Version: 0.2.1
